# How to make a select list with multiple columns of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

I am building a system that allows people to choose their own icons to go along with certain values. There are going to be many, many icons to choose from.

I would like to make a select box that has multiple columns with different options, because having a vertical list of 50+ icons would be absurd and not at all usable. I've found a lot of information on how to separate a single option into columns, but nothing that suggests that you could make a table-like arrangement of options. Is such a thing even possible? I've included a very quick mockup at the bottom of how I envision this looking to help clarify.

Here's the basic HTML I've been playing with (no icons involved):

```
<select class="custom-select" size="10" name="selectIcon">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

[image: Image of basic idea]

Comment: No, you cannot do this with a `<select>`. You’ll need your own HTML and CSS.

Comment: Search for a jQuery plugin that can transform ordinary `<select>` elements to something fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This jQuery plugin will help you achieve almost what you need with some configuration, but it will need to do some more work for design throw `styler` option you can achieve what you need.

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-multiple-items

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-styler

```
$(function() {
    $('#ms').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }).multipleSelect({
        placeholder: "Select Icon",
        width: '50%',
        single: true,
        multiple: true,
        multipleWidth: 40,
         styler: function(value) {
            return 'background: url(icons/' + value + '.png) no-repeat 100% 100%;';
         }
    });
});
```

[image]